# Derivation of velocity profile between two parallel cylinders

Tags: fluid-dynamics, rotational-dynamics, flow, continuum-mechanics, navier-stokes

Recently, I started learning about different flows such as Coutte, Poiseuille and Hagen-Poiseuille. When searching for the latter, I found this interesting image:

[image]

I thought that I might be able to solve it, since I've seen the derivation of the previous velocity profiles using Navier-Stokes equation. But to make it interesting, I thought that I might add some rotation as well. So we assume that the whole set up is rotating with an angular velocity $\vec{\omega} = \omega \hat{z}$. We also assume that the walls are solid of the cylindrical die, so although we have rotation itself, the velocities relative to the solid walls is still $0$. We further assume we are dealing with incompressible and laminar flow in steady state, and including gravity.

I expect that since we add rotation, the parabolic shapes should be tilted a slight angle towards the outer wall because of the centrifugal force added to the problem. I will make an ansatz for the velocity profile as $\vec{v} = v_z(r) \hat{z}$. Using Navier-Stokes equation

$$\mu \nabla^2 \vec{v} - \nabla p + \rho \vec{f} = \rho \frac{D\vec{v}}{Dt}$$

in cylindrical coordinates in the $\hat{r}$ - direction thus yields us the following relation

$$-\frac{\partial p}{\partial r} + \rho \omega^2 r = 0\Rightarrow p(r,z) = \rho \omega^2 r^2/2 + h(z) $$

for some arbitrary function $h(z)$, by using this image I found from the internet.

[image]

Now, in the $\hat{z}$ - direction, we get:

$$\mu\left(\frac{\partial^2v_z}{\partial r^2} + 1/r \frac{\partial v_z}{\partial r}\right) - \frac{\partial p}{\partial z} - \rho g = 0 \Rightarrow r\mu v_z''(r)+\mu v_z'(r) = r(\frac{\partial p}{\partial z} + \rho g) = r(h'(z)+\rho g)$$

Now, I want to apply the boundary conditions on $p$ to determine the function $h$. Since $h$ is solely dependent on $z$, by applying the condition that $p(r,0) = p_2$ and $p(r,L) = p_1$, we will inevitably get that $h(z)$ is dependent on $r$, which is a contradiction! What have I done wrong? To the image, I managed to find the solution without rotation and gravity, for which I managed to replicate their results. I'd be happy if anyone could provide me any hints or tips on what's going wrong here. I'm assuming maybe my assumption of the velocity profile is at fault, but I don't really know.

Comment: I think you should also consider the Coriolis force for the flow in the rotating frame.

Comment: Also, there also may a problem with boundary conditions. I can imagine a situation when the ansatz for $\vec{v}$ works, but it is inconsistent with the assumption that $p(r, 0)$ and $p(r, L)$ don't depend on $\vec{r}$.

Comment: @E.Anikin I thought about the coriolis effect at first, but with my assumption about the velocity profile, it would be non existent since the axis of rotation is parallell to the velocity profile. I think I’ll have to assume some more general form of the velocity field, but that will certainly increase the complexity of my problem. Regarding your 2nd comment, could you elaborate more on it? I’m sorry, but I don’t understand what you meant there. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for commenting on the Coriolis force! Regarding boundary conditions: in general, it is possible to solve the problem with boundary conditions on $p(r, 0) = p_0(r)$ and $p(r, L) = p_L(r)$, where $p_0(r)$ and $p_L(r)$ are arbitrary functions. However, the ansatz that you choose may not be valid for arbitrary $p_0(r)$ and $p)L(r)$, in particular $p_{0,L}(r) = \mathrm{const}$. Maybe you should try something like $p_{0}(r) = p_1 + \rho \omega^2 r^2/2$, $p_{L}(r) = p_2 + \rho \omega^2 r^2/2$.